# Angular 2 access child component function inside UI-VIEW

Tags: angular

My Project has both angular 1.5 and angular 2. I have below structure where I have 2 sibling component First-component and second-component. First component has Toggle button and second-component has UI-View of angular 1.5 where child component is rendered.

I want to access child-component ToggleData() when clicked on Toggle button in first-component.

I tried using View-child but it gives error as ToggleData() not found.

Please help me to solve this issue.

```js
//ChildComponent

ToggleData(){
}
```

```html
<First-component>

<button>Toggle</button>

</First-component>

<Second-component>

  <div ui-view>
  
    <child-component></child-component>
  
  </div>

</Second-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Since it is in a route:

Shared Service :

```
@Injectable()

export class SharedService{
    showData:boolean=false;       

    ToggleData(){
      //do something
      this.showData = !this.showData;
    }

}



export class Parent{

     constructor(public shared:SharedService){
     }


}

export class Child{
      //child can now access all shared data/functions
      // for example this.shared.showData  
      constructor(public shared:SharedService){
     }
}
```

Parent html:

```
<button (click)="shared.ToggleData()">Toggle</button>
```

hope this could help

**One way** is from the template:

```js
//ChildComponent

ToggleData(){     
}
```

```html
<First-component>

<button (click)="child.ToggleData()">Toggle</button>

</First-component>

<Second-component>

  <div ui-view>
  
    <child-component #child></child-component>
  
  </div>

</Second-component>
```

**Other way** is from the component by using View Child and then call

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child;

toggle(){
  this.child.ToggleData();
}
```

Comment: second one not working for me as it gives error as ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ToggleData' of undefined. For First one i can't assign #child as child-component is rendered on routing

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice it is a route, as far as i know you can't access child when he is a route,you could use a shared service that has the toggleData function or have the button inside the child

Comment: can u please help me with example

Comment: I edited the answer to show an example of shared data, I hope it would help